# how to get image name from postman

Tags: flask, postman

[image: How to get the name of the uploaded for example get screenshot.png ?]
How to get the name of the uploaded for example get screenshot.png ?

Comment: do you mean to get the name of the attachment in the body of the request ?
or do you mean to get the name of an attachment that is already uploaded ?

Comment: i wanted ame of the attachment in the body but i got answer => imagefile.filename

Answer (score 0):

you are sending to Flask a form, so to access this variable just use this code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    imagefile= request.form['imagefile']
    print(imagefile.filename)
```

and you will have the blob who represents this image and the name